# React JS Detect Close Button PiP ( Picture in picture)

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, picture-in-picture

I'm having trouble trying to detect an onClick or some type of event listener for the PIP feature in most browsers - specifically on Chrome.

Reading MDN docs and implementing their suggestions proved unsuccessful

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement/leavepictureinpicture_event

Here is my code so far which gives me a Cannot read properties of null error as there is no addEventListener for pipButton:

```
const video = document.getElementById('video');
const pipButton = document.getElementById('pipButton');

pipButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (document.pictureInPictureElement) {
    document
        .exitPictureInPicture()
        .catch(error => {
        // Error handling
    })
    } else {
    // Request Picture-in-Picture
    console.log('CLOSED PIP')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pipButton.addEventListener('leavepictureinpicture', function(event: any) {
      console.log('Left PiP');
      if (document.pictureInPictureElement) {
        document.exitPictureInPicture().catch((error: any) => {
          // Error handling
          console.log('error :>> ', error);
        });
      }
    });
```